# Передача переменной сквозь модули в Python

Tags: python

## main.py

```
import module1
x = 0
module1.func(x)
```

## module1.py

```
import module2
def func(x):
    module2.func(x)
```

## module2.py

```
import module3
def func(x):
    module3.func(x)
```

## module3.py

```
def func(x):
    y = x
```

Приходится передавать из модуля в модуль переменные, которые будут нужны **только** в самом последнем. Хотелось бы не тянуть `x` через модули 1 и 2, чтобы единожды использовать в модуле 3.

Можно это как-то обойти? Или я что-то неправильно делаю с самой архитектурой программы?

Comment: Непонятно, что через что куда тянется и почему нельзя просто импортировать нужный модуль там, где нужна переменная.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Есть ли проблема?

Нет ничего неправильного в **передаче значения** через параметры функций, неважно в каком количестве модулей эти функции объявлены.

### 2. Контейнеры

Если кол-во значений становится большим - используют контейнер какого угодно рода: начиная от `dict`, кончая инстансами специально созданных для этого классов.

Вообще, композиция значений и методов - это и есть основная мотивация в ООП.
(Прошу не комментировать и не пытаться вызывать на дискуссию по этому утверждению)

### 3. globals()

И, в конце концов, если Вы хотите прославиться среди коллег, Вы не опасаетесь косых взглядов и считаете, что "тесты - для слабаков" - можно вспомнить факт, что:

- модуль в python - это фактически синглтон
- `import` модуля - это запуск "конструктора" синглтона
- пространство глобальных имен - всегда открыто для манипуляции (в питоне вообще нет "полноценного" read-only)

## EDITED. P.S.

Проблема данного вопроса в том, что путаются понятия: "имени" и "значения".

Переменная - это совокупность "имя"-"значения" в некоем пространстве имен.

В `python` мы имеем пространства имен: `globals()`, `locals()`, `vars()` и контекст `with`.

"Передача переменной" как таковая - возможна, при прямой манипуляции с пространствами имен.

Что `python` - позволяет.

Но делать это, если вы не пишете, скажем, фреймворк для тестирования - врядли целесообразно.

Помните, что с мощью приходит ответственность.

Не плодите код, который никто после Вас (и Вы сами спустя пару недель) "без поллитры" не поймет.

Answer (score 3):

Возможность упростить этот код зависит от логической структуры программы, так что если бы вы привели больше информации по поводу вашей ситуации, ответить было бы намного проще.

Есть два базовых способа укоротить цепочку передачи аргумента: вызвать функцию напрямую или положить данные в третье место, доступное из `main` и `module3`.

1. Вызвать эту функцию (или её часть) напрямую, передав ей нужный аргумент:

   ```
   # main.py
   import module1
   import module3

   def call_func():
       module1.func()
       module3.func2(x)

   # module3.py
   def func():
       pass

   def func2(x):
       y = x
   ```

   Недостатки подобного подхода:

   - Модуль `main` теперь непосредственно знает о существовании модуля 3.
   - Должна быть возможность вынести код, работающий с `x` в отдельную функцию.
   - Усложняется интерфейс модуля 3.
   - ...
2. Вынести информацию, содержащуюся в `x` в какое-то третье место, доступное из `main` и `module3`:

   ```
   # main.py
   import module1

   module1.func()

   # settings.py
   x = 0

   # module3.py
   import settings

   def func():
       y = settings.x
   ```

   Недостатки:

   - Изменяемое глобальное состояние может усложнять тестирование и понимание программы.
   - Сложнее контролировать состояние при многопоточном исполнении кода.
   - ...

---

Эти подходы лишь обозначают возможности решения проблемы.

В вашем же случае я бы начал с того, чтобы понять, является ли параметр функции `module1.func` нелогичным или запутывающим. Если вызов функции `module1.func(x)` выглядит логично, то я бы подумал дважды перед тем, как удалять `x` из списка параметров.

Если же `x` там точно не должен быть, то имеет смысл подумать о структуре модулей и возможном выделении класса, который будет держать это состояние в себе.